# Web2py string processing exceptions.AttributeError

Tags: python, web2py

I have a Field that is intended for a user to write a custom query and submit button. The problem I'm having is that I can not use that string in an SQLFORM.grid()...

**python file**

```
def reports():

BlankString = ""
Report0=BlankString
Report1="some category"
Report2="some category"
Report3="some category"
Report4="some category"
Report5="some category"

myQuery="" #step1 - create a query to return results

results = SQLFORM.factory(buttons=[])

form = SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('report_type', label='Report Type', requires=IS_IN_SET([Report0, Report1,Report2, Report3, Report4, Report5])),
    Field('start_date', 'datetime', label='Start Date'),
    Field('end_date', 'datetime', label='End Date'),
    submit_button = T('Generate Report') )

userQueryForm = SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('userQuery', label=''), 
    submit_button = T('Generate Report')
    )


if userQueryForm.process(keepvalues=True).accepted:
    myQuery = userQueryForm.vars.userQuery
    if myQuery == BlankString:
        return dict(results=results, form=form, userQueryForm=userQueryForm)

if form.process(keepvalues=True).accepted:
    atype = form.vars.report_type

    if atype == BlankString:
        return dict(results=results, form=form, userQueryForm=userQueryForm)

    if atype==Report1:
        myQuery=(db.auth_user)
    elif atype==Report2:
        myQuery=(db.auth_group)


if myQuery != BlankString:
    results=SQLFORM.grid(myQuery,
                       csv=True, 
                       editable=False, 
                       create=False, 
                       details=False, 
                       deletable=False, 
                       searchable=False
                       )

return dict(results=results, form=form, userQueryForm=userQueryForm)
```

**HTML file**

```
{{left_sidebar_enabled=True}}
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<style>
    .container {
        width:100%;
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }
    .container div {
        width:100%;
    }
    .container .header {
        padding: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .container .content {
        display: none;
        padding : 5px;
    }
</style>

<h2>Reports</h2>

<p>Please select a report template or choose to write your own.</p>


<div class="container">
   <div class="header" onclick="StdRptClick()">
      <span>Standard report</span>
   </div>
<div class="content" id="StdRptID">
    {{=form}}
 </div>
 <div class="header" onclick="CstmRptClick()">
    <span>Advanced report</span>
 </div>
 <div class="content" id="CstmRptID">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <p>
                        Enter your desired query here.
                    </p>
                    {{=userQueryForm}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
   {{option = form.vars.report_type}}
   {{option2 = form.vars.userQuery}}
   <h3>{{=option2}}</h3>   
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function RequestReport()
    {
        if( $('#CustomQueryID').val() == '')
        {
           alert("Query can not be blank");
           return;
       }
       else
       {
           alert("something");
       }
   }

   function StdRptClick()
   {
       if( $('#no_table_report_type').val() == '')
       {
              $('#no_table_start_date__row').hide();
              $('#no_table_end_date__row').hide();
       }

       $('#CstmRptID').slideUp();
       $('#StdRptID').slideToggle();

   }

  function CstmRptClick()
  {
       $('#StdRptID').slideUp();
       $('#CstmRptID').slideToggle();
  }

  $('#no_table_report_type__row').on('change',
       function()
       {
           var selText = ($('#no_table_report_type').val());

           if( selText == '')
           {
               $('#no_table_start_date__row').hide();
               $('#no_table_end_date__row').hide();
           }
           else
           {

               $('#no_table_start_date__row').show();
               $('#no_table_end_date__row').show();
           }
       });
```

When ever i try to put a query in to  `userQuery` and hit the submit button, 
I get an error saying

"
 'str' object has no attribute '_db'"

How can I use the query the user entered?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `SQLFORM.grid` must be a DAL [`Table` object](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Table-constructor) or [`Query` object](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Query--Set--Rows). You should also be careful about allowing users to enter arbitrary queries, as you could be opening yourself to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

If you want to allow users to construct custom queries, you should provide a more constrained interface, and then convert the inputs to a proper DAL `Query`. One option is to use [`db.smart_query`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#smart_query--experimental-) to parse the user input (you will need to provide some instruction regarding the required syntax). If you want to provide a more structured interface for the user to build the query, you can try [`SQLFORM.search_menu`](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/16f60d5cfffd7782f149fefe9096e6b033287d2a/gluon/sqlhtml.py#L1955) (it is not documented in the book because it is mainly intended for internal use by `SQLFORM.grid`, but you can use it separately). You should be able to pass queries created via `SQLFORM.search_menu` to `db.smart_query` in order to create a DAL `Query` (this is how the grid search functionality works).

Finally, since your goal appears to be to provide the user with a grid based on a custom query, you might instead consider simply providing a grid with all the data to the user, and then let the user use the built-in advanced search functionality to get the desired results. If you don't want the user to see all the data initially, you can start by showing only the grid search box:

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.mytable)
grid = grid if 'keywords' in request.get_vars else grid.element('.web2py_console')
```

The above would return only the ".web2py_console" part of the grid (i.e., the search box) when no search query has been submitted (e.g., when the page first loads).